# utf16 of character has 2 negative numbers when converted to bytes

Tags: java, encoding, utf-16

The character "A" should have unicode of 0x41 in UTF8 and 0x0041 in UTF16, when I try to get the bytes for A I get 2 negative numbers,  why I don't get 0 0 0 65 ?

```
String x = "A";
byte[] bytes = x.getBytes("UTF16");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
```

[-2, -1, 0, 65]

Comment: those first two bytes look like a [byte order mark](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark): 0xFE and 0xFF respectively. If you look at the [`Charset` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) documentation this is mentioned for UTF-16

Comment: @Botje aah that explains it , do you want to answer it ? or shall I remove because it's duplicate ? I'm not sure if it's asked somewhere